# Internal Truth Machine

Tags: code-golf, source-layout, self-referential

It's a [normal truth machine](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Truth-machine) but instead of taking input, it uses the first character of the program. Thus, internal.

The 0 and 1 are plain characters, i.e. ASCII code 0x30 and 0x31 respectively.

Example: `0abcd` prints 0 and halts, and `1abcd` prints 1 infinitely. Then your submission is `abcd`, whose score is 4 bytes. The 0 or 1 (the first character of the program) is not counted towards your score.

Of course, you're not allowed to look inside the file itself. Like a quine.

### Leaderboard

Here is a Stack Snippet to generate both a regular leaderboard and an overview of winners by language.

```js
/* Configuration */

var QUESTION_ID = 198288; // Obtain this from the url
// It will be like https://XYZ.stackexchange.com/questions/QUESTION_ID/... on any question page
var ANSWER_FILTER = "!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe";
var COMMENT_FILTER = "!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk";
var OVERRIDE_USER = 48934; // This should be the user ID of the challenge author.

/* App */

var answers = [], answers_hash, answer_ids, answer_page = 1, more_answers = true, comment_page;

function answersUrl(index) {
  return "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/" +  QUESTION_ID + "/answers?page=" + index + "&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter=" + ANSWER_FILTER;
}

function commentUrl(index, answers) {
  return "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/" + answers.join(';') + "/comments?page=" + index + "&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter=" + COMMENT_FILTER;
}

function getAnswers() {
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: answersUrl(answer_page++),
    method: "get",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function (data) {
      answers.push.apply(answers, data.items);
      answers_hash = [];
      answer_ids = [];
      data.items.forEach(function(a) {
        a.comments = [];
        var id = +a.share_link.match(/\d+/);
        answer_ids.push(id);
        answers_hash[id] = a;
      });
      if (!data.has_more) more_answers = false;
      comment_page = 1;
      getComments();
    }
  });
}

function getComments() {
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: commentUrl(comment_page++, answer_ids),
    method: "get",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function (data) {
      data.items.forEach(function(c) {
        if (c.owner.user_id === OVERRIDE_USER)
          answers_hash[c.post_id].comments.push(c);
      });
      if (data.has_more) getComments();
      else if (more_answers) getAnswers();
      else process();
    }
  });  
}

getAnswers();

var SCORE_REG = /<h\d>\s*([^\n,]*[^\s,]),.*?(\d+)(?=[^\n\d<>]*(?:<(?:s>[^\n<>]*<\/s>|[^\n<>]+>)[^\n\d<>]*)*<\/h\d>)/;

var OVERRIDE_REG = /^Override\s*header:\s*/i;

function getAuthorName(a) {
  return a.owner.display_name;
}

function process() {
  var valid = [];
  
  answers.forEach(function(a) {
    var body = a.body;
    a.comments.forEach(function(c) {
      if(OVERRIDE_REG.test(c.body))
        body = '<h1>' + c.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG, '') + '</h1>';
    });
    
    var match = body.match(SCORE_REG);
    if (match)
      valid.push({
        user: getAuthorName(a),
        size: +match[2],
        language: match[1],
        link: a.share_link,
      });
    
  });
  
  valid.sort(function (a, b) {
    var aB = a.size,
        bB = b.size;
    return aB - bB
  });

  var languages = {};
  var place = 1;
  var lastSize = null;
  var lastPlace = 1;
  valid.forEach(function (a) {
    if (a.size != lastSize)
      lastPlace = place;
    lastSize = a.size;
    ++place;
    
    var answer = jQuery("#answer-template").html();
    answer = answer.replace("{{PLACE}}", lastPlace + ".")
                   .replace("{{NAME}}", a.user)
                   .replace("{{LANGUAGE}}", a.language)
                   .replace("{{SIZE}}", a.size)
                   .replace("{{LINK}}", a.link);
    answer = jQuery(answer);
    jQuery("#answers").append(answer);

    var lang = a.language;
    if (/<a/.test(lang)) lang = jQuery(lang).text();
    
    languages[lang] = languages[lang] || {lang: a.language, user: a.user, size: a.size, link: a.link};
  });

  var langs = [];
  for (var lang in languages)
    if (languages.hasOwnProperty(lang))
      langs.push(languages[lang]);

  langs.sort(function (a, b) {
    if (a.lang > b.lang) return 1;
    if (a.lang < b.lang) return -1;
    return 0;
  });

  for (var i = 0; i < langs.length; ++i)
  {
    var language = jQuery("#language-template").html();
    var lang = langs[i];
    language = language.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}", lang.lang)
                       .replace("{{NAME}}", lang.user)
                       .replace("{{SIZE}}", lang.size)
                       .replace("{{LINK}}", lang.link);
    language = jQuery(language);
    jQuery("#languages").append(language);
  }

}
```

```css
body { text-align: left !important}

#answer-list {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 290px;
  float: left;
}

#language-list {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 290px;
  float: left;
}

table thead {
  font-weight: bold;
}

table td {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b">
<div id="answer-list">
  <h2>Leaderboard</h2>
  <table class="answer-list">
    <thead>
      <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="answers">

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div id="language-list">
  <h2>Winners by Language</h2>
  <table class="language-list">
    <thead>
      <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="languages">

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<table style="display: none">
  <tbody id="answer-template">
    <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table style="display: none">
  <tbody id="language-template">
    <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Wait, why did you post it *so* fast from the Sandbox?

Comment: So, to make sure I understand, this requires two programs in the same language that differ only in the first character being either 0 or 1?

Comment: Yes, and it acts like an input to the normal truth machine.

Comment: Does the input bit count as part of the program?

Comment: Well, when I had it in mind, I thought of including it, but now, I guess not.

Comment: Must output be STDOUT or is STDERR or exit code also fine?

Comment: Quasi-duplicate of [Implement a Truth-Machine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/62732/implement-a-truth-machine). The added restriction on input doesn't make it distinct in an interesting way.

Comment: I agree with the suggested dupe. Let's dupe-hammer this if Grimmy's comment reaches 4 votes (assuming it's not closed as dupe first by standard votes)

Comment: @Grimy, My code would change quite a bit though, shaving [ten bytes off](http://morphett.info/turing/turing.html?54f2449f004c02d34559b4a68ebe7e5d), and my answer here wouldn't work.

Comment: @LuisMendo, But I think one major qualification for whether a question here is a duplicate is whether the answers here would answer the question for the proposed duplicate (even with trivial changes). But I don't think that is the case. Maybe for a couple of languages. But not for many of these. The [Lua answer there](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/93864) would not work here, and in fact, it's impossible to answer this challenge here in Lua. That certainly has to be taken into consideration.

Comment: Although I agree with _Grimmy_ and something else could have been chosen as output for `1`/`0` respectively, I don't really see it as a dupe. Uninteresting since we already have the other challenge: definitely; but dupe: not really. This challenge isn't even possible in Java or Whitespace for example (a.f.a.i.k.), and although the core part is indeed the same, getting around that leading `0`/`1` will be tricky in some languages. EDIT: Ah, @ouflak already mentioned everything I said I now see..

Comment: @ouflak, Kevin: Ok, not a dupe then

Answer (score 35):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 29 bytes

```python
 or~print(0)
while 1:print(1)
```

A full program, which if prefixed with `0` will print `0` then halt, exiting with an error, or if prefixed with `1` will print `1` forever.

**[Try 0 online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/30Ahv6iuoCgzr0TDQJOrPCMzJ1XB0AoiYKgJlE/MS9GosLI11MwvUkBTVwFVV6EJAA)**
**[Try 1 online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/31Ahv6iuoCgzr0TDQJOrPCMzJ1XB0AoiYKj5/79BYl6KRoWVraFmfpECmroKqLoKTQA)**

The right of a logical `or` is only executed if the left is falsey (which `0` is, while `1` is not).

If the prefix is `0` the argument, `print(0)`, of bitwise-not, `~`, is evaluated - this has a side-effect of printing `0` and returns `None` which is an invalid argument for `~` causing an error which halts the program.

If the prefix is `1` the code `~print(0)` is not evaluated  and the infinite loop of `while 1:print(1)` is reached.

Comment: That's really clever. Have an upvote.

Comment: It's just as long, but `exit('0')` instead of `~print(0)` would work without the error...

Comment: @AVee True, although `exit` prints to stderr which would mean different output streams for the two programs - I'd  want to check that was acceptable.

Answer (score 19):

### [W](https://github.com/a-ee/w), 2 bytes

You know, duplicate the first character and apply while. Simple enough.

```
:w
```

### Explanation, applied the bits

```
1:  % The condition and the body is both 1
  w % While the condition 1 is true, output 1
```

### Explanation 2

```
0:  % The condition and the body is both 0
  w % This while does not get executed
    % The condition 0 gets returned & printed
```

Comment: I really like this solution. Short and to the point. +1

Answer (score 9):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 20 bytes

```r
->a
while(print(a))0
```

[0Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/30DXLpGrPCMzJ1WjoCgzr0QjUVPT4P9/AA)

[1Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/31DXLpGrPCMzJ1WjoCgzr0QjUVPT4P9/AA)

Uses rightwards assignment `->`, which I now seem to use about [once](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/191416/86301) [a](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/196869/86301) [month](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/197103/86301) on this site (and never anywhere else).

Comment: I knew this would be here. The only use I've ever thought of for `->` outside of the site is at the end of a long pipe expression, but that's actually more confusing for future readers than it's worth.

Comment: @Giuseppe maybe you paste some data into console, and then realized that you need assign it to some variable...

Comment: @tsh that's pretty much where I use it, when I'm skunkworksing some big pipe expression and need to use it as a vector mask or something

Comment: I use it in `setClass` statements (you certainly don't have to, it just looks nicer to me to do `setClass("myClass",...) -> myClass` though I can't put my finger on why)

Answer (score 9):

## x86-16 machine code, IBM PC DOS, 11 bytes

**Binary:**

(`0` example)

```
00000000: 3002 ad8a d03c 30cd 2175 fcc3            0....<0.!u..
```

(`1` example)

```
00000000: 3102 ad8a d03c 30cd 2175 fcc3            1....<0.!u..
```

**Unassembled listing:**

```
?? 02       DB  ?, 2        ; first byte is '1' or '0', second byte is DOS write char fnc
AD          LODSW           ; load input from [SI] into AL, INT 21H function 2 in AH
8A D0       MOV  DL, AL     ; output to DL
3C 30       CMP  AL, '0'    ; is input 0?
        OUTPUT: 
CD 21       INT  21H        ; write to console
75 FC       JNZ  OUTPUT     ; if not a '0', keep looping forever
C3          RET             ; return to DOS (only if it was a 0)
```

**Explanation:**

The first byte of the program is either a `'0'` or a `'1'`, and combined with a second byte of `2` (more on that later) decodes to a benign instruction of either `XOR [BP+SI], AL` or `XOR [BP+SI], AX`.  In PC DOS, many registers are [initialized to known values](http://www.fysnet.net/yourhelp.htm), so we know that `AX` is `0`, and `SI` is `100H` which is the first byte of the program.  Whatever memory address `[BP+SI]` translates to, it simply XOR's `0` to it, doing nothing.

The `LODSW` instruction puts the input byte into the `AL` register and a `2` into the AH register, which is the DOS `INT 21H` API function number to write an ASCII char in `DL` to the console.

The input is compared and `ZF` (zero flag) is set "true" if input is a `0`.  The char is written to the console and if `ZF` is not zero, it will loop indefinitely.

**Output of both variants:**

[image]

Answer (score 7):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 32 bytes

```hs
!f=f 0
_!f=f 1*>0!f
main=0!print
```

I think this is the only answer posted so far where the first character (the digit) isn't the entry point.

Anyway, explanation: I'm creating an operator function called `!`, and defining it by cases. We enter the top case if the left operand matches the program's first digit, and the bottom case otherwise. The right operand is bound to `f` in both cases (and it happens to always be `print`). In the top case, we just print a 0. In the bottom case, we print a 1, and then recursively call ourself with the same operands. (We know the left operand will always be 0.) Finally, `main`, the entry point, calls our operator with `0` and `print`.

[Try it online with 0!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/30AxzTZNwYArHkwbatkBBbhyEzPzbA0UC4oy80r@/wcA)
[Try it online with 1!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/31AxzTZNwYArHkwbatkZKKZx5SZm5tkaKBYUZeaV/P8PAA)

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 3 bytes

```
µ=0
```

[Try `0µ=0` online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f4NBWW4P//wE)

[Try `1µ=0` online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f8NBWW4P//wE)

Also 3 bytes:

```
i[,
```

[Try `0i[,` online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fIDNa5/9/AA)

[Try `1i[,` online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fMDNa5/9/AA)

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
Ṅḷ¿
```

**[Try 0 online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/g4c6Whzu2H9r//z8A)**
**[Try 1 online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/w4c6Whzu2H9r//z8A)**

```
 Ṅḷ¿ - Main Link: no arguments
.    - set Left to 0 or 1
   ¿ - while...
  ḷ  - ...condition: Left
 Ṅ   - ...do: print and yield (Left)
     - implicit print (Left)
```

Answer (score 6):

## Scratch 3.0, 10 blocks/80 bytes

[image: Program]

As SB Syntax:

```
//1 or 0
repeat until<(n)=[0
say[1
end
say[0
define 0
set [n v]to[0
define 1
set[n v]to[1
```

It's more of a snippet than a program, but it works.

[Try it on<s>line</s> Scratch!](https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/361363482/)

Answer (score 6):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish),  <s>6</s>  5 bytes

-1 thanks to Jo King!

```
:n?!;
```

**[Try 0 online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/38Aqz17R@v9/AA)**
**[Try 1 online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/39Aqz17R@v9/AA)**

#### How?

Instruction pointer starts at the top left (i.e. 0 or 1) facing right. If the instruction pointer leaves the code it wraps around to the other side, continuing in the same direction.

```
X:n?!; -               X=0                X=1
X      - push X          {0}                {1}
 :     - duplicate       {0,0}              {1,1}
  n    - pop & print     {0,} "0"           {1} "1"
   ?   - pop & if...     {}                 {}
    !  - ...truthy:      skip & wrap to X
     ; - ...falsey:                         exit
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Labyrinth](https://github.com/m-ender/labyrinth), 5 bytes

```
"
!"@
```

**[Try 0 online!](https://tio.run/##y0lMqizKzCvJ@P/fQIlLUcnh/38A)**
**[Try 1 online!](https://tio.run/##y0lMqizKzCvJ@P/fUIlLUcnh/38A)**

#### How?

Instruction pointer starts at the top left (i.e. `0` or `1`) facing right, the stack starts as infinite zeros.

**0:**

```
0"
!"@
```

```
  - stack = {0,0,0,...} (infinite supply of zeros)
0 - multiply top of stack by 10 and add 0 {0,0,0,...}
  - 2 neighbours, 0 -> go forward
" - no-op {0,0,0,...}
  - 2 neighbours -> go forward
" - no-op {0,0,0,...}
  - 3 neighbours T-junction from stem, 0 -> turn around
" - no-op {0,0,0,...}
  - 2 neighbours -> go forward
0 - multiply top of stack by 10 and add 0 {0,0,0,...}
  - 2 neighbours -> go forward
! - pop top of stack, print as decimal "0" {0,0,0,...}
  - 2 neighbours -> go forward
" - no-op {0,0,0,...}
  - 3 neighbours T-junction from side, 0 -> go forward
@ - exit labyrinth
```

**1:**

```
1"
!"@
```

```
  - stack = {0,0,0,...} (infinite supply of zeros)
1 - multiply top of stack by 10 and add 1 {1,0,0,...}
  - 2 neighbours -> go forward
" - no-op {1,0,0,...}
  - 2 neighbours -> go forward
" - no-op {1,0,0,...}
  - 3 neighbours T-junction from stem, 1 -> turn right
! - pop top of stack, print as decimal "1" {0,0,0,...}
  - 2 neighbours -> go forward
1 - multiply top of stack by 10 and add 1 {1,0,0,...}
  - ...etc.
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), <strike>65</strike> <strike>63</strike> 56 bytes

Pyth's prefix operators don't really suit well to this challenge...

```
Ws@`$__import__("inspect").stack()[1][0].f_locals$_101
1
```

Edit 1: Saved 2 bytes by letting Pyth do the dictionary index, and using `h` instead of `@<py_code>0` because I remembered it exists.

Edit 2: Saved 7 bytes because @isaacg found an even sillier trick :)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/3yC82CFBJT4@M7cgv6gkPl5DKTOvuCA1uURJU6@4JDE5W0Mz2jA22iBWLy0@Jz85MadYJd7QwJDL8P9/AA)

Comment: I really like this! I found a even sillier way to shorten it a bit more by removing the need for the "pyth_code" index. 56 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/3yC82CFBJT4@M7cgv6gkPl5DKTOvuCA1uURJU6@4JDE5W0Mz2jA22iBWLy0@Jz85MadYJd7QwJDL8P9/AA "Pyth – Try It Online")

Comment: @issacg Clever! also thanks for making such a fun little language to play with, I've sunk more time into it than I'd like to admit >.<

Comment: I'm really glad you've enjoyed it!

Answer (score 4):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), <s>12</s> 10 bytes

```
:?vn;
 n:<
```

-2 bytes thanks to @JonathanAllan

### Answer History

```
 :?vn;
>:n:<
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/X8HKvizPmsvOKs/K5v9/AA)

or

[Try it with `1`](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/31DByr4sz5rLzirPyub/fwA)

[Try it with `0`](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/30DByr4sz5rLzirPyub/fwA)

### Explained

[image: Gif showing execution path with 0]

[image: Gif showing execution path with 0]

Path visualiser is https://fishlanguage.com/

Gif converter is https://www.onlineconverter.com/video-to-gif

Comment: Save two using [wrapping](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/39DKvizPmkshz8rm/38A).

Comment: [5 bytes](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/39Aqz17R@v9/AA) by keeping it 1D.

Comment: But then that would be the same as the other 5 byte ><> answer

Comment: Oh, didn't notice that.

Answer (score 4):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 8 bytes<sup>SBCS</sup>

```apl
{⍞←⍺}⍣≠1
```

[0Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///36D6Ue@8R20THvXuqn3Uu/hR5wLD//8B)
[1Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///37D6Ue@8R20THvXuqn3Uu/hR5wLD//8B)

Prints to stderr.

#### How they work

```apl
0{⍞←⍺}⍣≠1
 {⍞←⍺}⍣≠   ⍝ Iterate {⍞←⍺} until (next value)≠(prev value) is true
 {⍞←⍺}     ⍝ First iteration: print and return left arg (0)
       ≠   ⍝ (next value)=0, (prev value)=1, so 0≠1 is true
           ⍝ Function terminates

1{⍞←⍺}⍣≠1
 {⍞←⍺}⍣≠   ⍝ Iterate {⍞←⍺} until (next value)≠(prev value) is true
 {⍞←⍺}     ⍝ First iteration: print and return left arg (1)
       ≠   ⍝ (next value)=1, (prev value)=1, so 1≠1 is false
 {⍞←⍺}     ⍝ Second and subsequent iterations: called with the same arg (1)
           ⍝ Never terminates; prints 1 infinitely
```

Comment: I tried translating this into J to improve my current approach but wasn't able to.  Is J's `^:v^:_` just fundamentally different from the APL iterate or am I missing something?

Comment: @Jonah I guess it's because J's `^:_` is special-cased to find the fixed point. So it stops not only when `v` gives 0, but also when the right argument doesn't change.

Comment: Yeah that was the problem.

Answer (score 4):

### [Befunge-93](https://github.com/catseye/Befunge-93), 5 bytes

```
:_.@#
```

[Try 0 online](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT/3/38AqXs9B@f9/AA)

[Try 1 online](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT/3/39AqXs9B@f9/AA)

First submission, and I only started learning Funge yesterday, so it's very likely there's a shorter solution.

I tried to find a way to remove the need for the ":" but I couldn't.

Comment: Welcome to CGCC! This is a very nice solution

Answer (score 4):

## [Raku](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>14</s> 11 bytes

```perl6
,1...&say^1
```

[0Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7b/Bfx1BPT0@tOLEyzvD/fwA) [1Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7b/hfx1BPT0@tOLEyzvD/fwA)

Abuses the range operator to loop infinitely and the XOR Junction (`^`) to print and to evaluate if the range should stop.

Answer (score 3):

## [Turing Machine Code](http://morphett.info/turing/turing.html), <s>29</s> bytes or 28 bytes

With the strange rule that the leading '0' or '1' doesn't count towards the byte count.

```
0 0 1 * 1
* _ 0 * 1
* 1 1 r 1
```

[Try '0' online!](http://morphett.info/turing/turing.html?e5750226d485c40676e8bfce2a18ffab)

```
1 0 1 * 1
* _ 0 * 1
* 1 1 r 1
```

[Try '1' online!](http://morphett.info/turing/turing.html?bc348194dbef0b4ddae4c81dbfff4544)

Answer (score 3):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 24 bytes

```php
?:die(0.);for(;;)echo 1;
```

Uses ternary condition knowing that in PHP one of the alternatives can be empty and i doesn't need to be assigned to a variable.

0: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAkDeytUjJTNQz0NK3T8os0rK01U5Mz8hUMrf//BwA)

1: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAkDe2tUjJTNQz0NK3T8os0rK01U5Mz8hUMrf//BwA)

Edit: had to add `'0'` to properly echo zero

Edit2: Had forgotten that `die` was synonym of `exit` (thanks manual)

Edit3: saved 1 byte with `for(;;)` instead of `while(1)`

Edit4: saved 1 byte with `die(0.)` instead of `die('0')` thanks to @Christoph

Comment: You can use `die(0.);` to save a byte only integers get returned instead of printed.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 37 bytes

```python
and exec('while 1:print(1)');print(0)
```

0: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/3yAxL0UhtSI1WUO9PCMzJ1XB0KqgKDOvRMNQU13TGsI00Pz/HwA)
1: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/3zAxL0UhtSI1WUO9PCMzJ1XB0KqgKDOvRMNQU13TGsI00Pz/HwA)

Answer (score 3):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), 3 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
Äo↑
```

[Try `0Äo↑` online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/9/gcEv@o7aJ//8DAA)
[Try `1Äo↑` online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/9/wcEv@o7aJ//8DAA)

**Explanation:**

```python
1     # Push 1
   ↑  # While true without popping,
 Ä    # by using a single builtin as inner block:
  o   #  Print with trailing newline without popping

0     # Push 0
   ↑  # While true without popping
      # (output the entire stack joined together implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 3):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 21 bytes

```powershell
0|?{$_}|%{for(){1}};0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/37DGvlolvrZGtTotv0hDs9qwttba4P9/AA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), 4 bytes

```
{:|④
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N//@/2qrm0cTF////180oAgA)

It seems I'm a bit late to the party! ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

<s>Anyhow, this is simply a modification of the usual truth machine</s> This is literally the same truth machine as it would be if we didn't have to place the digit at the start. Funny how implicit input works.

By this, I mean it doesn't matter if y'all place the digit at the start or you place it in input.

(⌐■◡■)

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript, 34 bytes

```javascript
?(_=>{for(;;)alert(1)})():alert(0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEtLshMSS3Kzc/LTq38n5iTWlRim5yfV5yfk6qXk5/@314j3tauOi2/SMPaWhMsrWGoWaupoWkF4Rho/v8PAA)

Comment: Would a recursive function be legal, along the lines of `(g=_=>g(alert(1)))()`?

Comment: `?(a=1):(a=0);do alert(a);while(a)` is 33 bytes long

Comment: `?eval('for(;;)alert(1)'):alert(0)` is 33 bytes also.

Comment: You can also remove brackets from @tsh suggestion `?a=1:a=0;do alert(a);while(a)`

Comment: `?a=1:a=2;for(;a;)alert(a&=1)` funny version still based on @tsh suggestion

Comment: @AZTECCO I'd post yours as it's own answer, I feel it's a little too novel for me to take...

Answer (score 3):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), <s>15</s> 9 bytes

```
?\0n;
n1<
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/3z7GIM@aK8/Q5v9/AA)

- -6 bytes thanks to JoKing

My first fish program<s>, doesn't beat the other one but I wanted to post it anyway.</s> Beats the other one now!

#### Explanation:

For 0:
`0?` skip the next command
`0` push `0` to the stack
`n` output the top of the stack
`;` terminate
For 1:
`1?` don't skip the next command (no-op)
`\` mirror down
`>` switch direction to forward
`1` push `1` to the stack
`n` output, then wrap round

Comment: @JoKing *"d"o can be replaced with dn* I tried that but TIO outputs unrecognised characters... am I missing something?

Comment: Oh right I used `o` not `n` because apparently I can't read. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 6 bytes

```
1ＷΣ⊟ＫＡＤ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvREPJUEnTmqs8IzMnVUEjuDRXIyC/QCMgNTXbMSdHQxMIFFxKcws0NK3///@vW5YDAA) Link is to verbose version of code.

```
0ＷΣ⊟ＫＡＤ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvREPJQEnTmqs8IzMnVUEjuDRXIyC/QCMgNTXbMSdHQxMIFFxKcws0NK3///@vW5YDAA) Link is to verbose version of code.

Explanation: The leading `1` or `0` simply prints literally to the canvas. There then follows a `while` loop, the condition of which is the digital sum of the last character on the canvas. Thus if this is zero, the loop never gets off the ground, and the canvas gets implicitly output with the `0` still on it. However, if this is a non-zero digit, such as `1`, then the loop will dump a copy of the canvas for ever. (Note that the `dump` command has a rate limit on it, so that TIO will time out before the output reaches the size limit.)

There are a few variants with the same byte count, such as using `Cast` rather than `Sum`, or `Maximum` or `Minimum` rather than `Pop`, or even by using `Count` or `Find` instead.

Answer (score 3):

## [Alchemist](https://github.com/bforte/Alchemist), 27 bytes

```
a->a+Out_b
_+0a->a+b
a+b->_
```

[Try it online with 0!](https://tio.run/##S8xJzkjNzSwu@f/fIFHXLlHbv7QkPokrXhvCS@ICYl27@P//AQ)

[Try it online with 1!](https://tio.run/##S8xJzkjNzSwu@f/fMFHXLlHbv7QkPokrXtsAzEviAmJdu/j//wE)

This was a bit tricky.  Every execution path up to the first application of the first line must be possible in both programs, and the two possible patterns in the first line are mutually exclusive.  Hence, in order for the program to work, execution up to that point must be non-deterministic.  This program swaps infinitely between two states until the first line is applied.

```
0a->a+Out_b    # the 0 version: from the initial state, add an a to halt and output 0
1a->a+Out_b    # the 1 version: from the a+b state, output 1 and leave the state unchanged
_+0a->a+b      # From the initial state, move to the a+b state
a+b->_         # From the a+b state, move to the initial state
```

A deterministic solution is possible by starting the first line with a two-digit number, but this is [14 bytes longer](https://tio.run/##S8xJzkjNzSwu@f/fMFE7WdcuiSte184QxOZK0jZIBApo@5eWxCcBeUAOmPn//3/dFAA).

Comment: The second program can be shortened to [36 bytes](https://tio.run/##S8xJzkjNzSwu@f/fMFE7XtcuiStJ2yARSGv7l5bEg3hADpipaGiY@P//f90UAA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>16</s> 15 bytes

*-1 byte thanks to Jo King*

```perl6
&&1 xx*X[&put]$
```

[Try0 it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/99ATc1QoaJCKyJaraC0JFbl/38A)
[Try1 it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/99QTc1QoaJCKyJaraC0JFbl/38A)

Comment: Using `X` with a custom operator is very clever. My thought was to use `...`, but that only ties with your old solution. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/99AR1tLT0@vWq84sdJaUSW@9v9/AA "Perl 6 – Try It Online")

Comment: @JoKing You can replace `+*` with `1` for -1 byte, so both approaches are tied again.

Comment: Aha! [Figured out how to eliminate another byte from my solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/209210/76162)

Answer (score 3):

## [Cubix](https://github.com/ETHproductions/cubix), 5 bytes

```
^O?@u
```

0 [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy5Nyqz4/98gzt/eofT/fwA)

1 [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy5Nyqz4/98wzt/eofT/fwA)

Maps onto the cube like

```
  0
^ O ? @
  u
```

- `^` Redirect up onto the top face
- `0` or `1` pushed to the stack
- `?` test

  - `uO?@` if `0` then u-turn onto the integer output pass through the  test again and halt
  - `O^` if `1` output the integer and redirect up again

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 38 bytes

```python
0 or print(0)or exit()
while 1:print(1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/30Ahv0ihoCgzr0TDQBPITK3ILNHQ5CrPyMxJVTC0gsgYav7/DwA)

```python
1 or print(0)or exit()
while 1:print(1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/31Ahv0ihoCgzr0TDQBPITK3ILNHQ5CrPyMxJVTC0gsgYav7/DwA)

---

If output to STDERR is allowed (30 bytes):

```python
0 or exit('0')
while 1:print(1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/30Ahv0ghtSKzREPdQF2TqzwjMydVwdCqoCgzr0TDUPP/fwA)

---

If output as exit code is allowed (28 bytes):

```python
0 or exit(0)
while 1:print(1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/30Ahv0ghtSKzRMNAk6s8IzMnVcHQqqAoM69Ew1Dz/38A)

Comment: I was not expecting that to be possible

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 17 bytes

```ruby
>0?loop{p 1}:p(0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfnJ@Saquurv7fzsA@Jz@/oLpAwbDWqkDDQPM/UJQrtSwxR8HeQBukTK@4pCizACpkiCT0HwA)

Answer (score 2):

## TI-BASIC, 10 bytes

```
Repeat not(Ans:Disp Ans:End:"
```

Add either `0:` or `1:` to the beginning of the code to get the desired output.
Output is either just 0 or an infinite amount of 1s.

`Repeat`  loops until its condition is true and ignores the condition for the first loop.
Thus, `not(Ans` will be 1 if `0:` is added and 0 if `1:` is added.

An empty string is added to the end of the program to prevent it from printing `Done`.

**Examples:**

prgmA:  `0:Repeat not(Ans:Disp Ans:End:"`

prgmB:  `1:Repeat not(Ans:Disp Ans:End:"`

```
prgmA
              0

prgmB
              1
              1
              1
              1
              1
              1
              1
```

**Note:** TI-BASIC is a tokenized language.  Character count does *not* equal byte count.

Answer (score 2):

## [Triangular](https://github.com/aaronryank/triangular), 9 bytes

```
.%).?/%(<
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KynKTMxLL81JLPr/31BPVVPPXl9Vw@b/fwA)

Formatted, it looks like this, with X being the number:

```
   X
  . %
 ) . ?
/ % ( <
```

How it works:

- The instruction pointer begins at the top going southeast. It hits the first byte which is the number and pushes that to the stack.
- `%` prints the top of the stack as a number.
- `?` skips the next instruction if the top of the stack is not positive. This effectively ends the program if the first byte was zero.
- `<` redirects the IP left.
- `(` creates a jump point, `%` prints the top of the stack, `)` unconditionally jumps to the most recent jump point.

Answer (score 2):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 46 bytes

```bash
 2>t
f()(echo 1;f)
grep -q '0: c' t&&echo 0||f
```

[False Version](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/30DByK6EK01DUyM1OSNfwdA6TZMrvSi1QEG3UEHdwEohWV2hRE0NLGdQU5P2n@s/AA)

[True Version](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/31DByK6EK01DUyM1OSNfwdA6TZMrvSi1QEG3UEHdwEohWV2hRE0NLGdQU5P2n@s/AA) - You may have to stop TIO before you'll see the output of ones.

We redirect the error message for the missing command (0 or 1) to a file named `t`, and then we use `grep` to find out which error occured and branch off it.

Answer (score 2):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 22 bytes

```matlab
;do disp(ans)until!ans
```

- [Try 0 online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f/fwDolXyEls7hAIzGvWLM0ryQzRxHI@v8fAA)
- [Try 1 online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f/f0DolXyEls7hAIzGvWLM0ryQzRxHI@v8fAA)

If additional `ans =` on each line is allowed, this could be 17 bytes: [`;do ans until!ans`](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f/fwDolXyEls7hAIzGvWLM0ryQzRxHI@v8fAA)

Answer (score 2):

## Commodore 64 Basic, 26 bytes

Memory address $0039 (or 57 decimal) contains the low byte of the current line number.

```
0 PRINT PEEK(57):IF PEEK(57)=1 THEN 1
```

or

```
1 PRINT PEEK(57):IF PEEK(57)=1 THEN 1
```

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 23 bytes

```
 echo@0`($:[echo@1)@.*1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/XyE1OSPfwSBBQ8UqGsw01HTQ0zL8z/UfAA)

[False](https://tio.run/##y/r/30AhNTkj38EgQUPFKhrMNNR00NMy/M/1HwA)

[True](https://tio.run/##y/r/31AhNTkj38EgQUPFKhrMNNR00NMy/M/1HwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Forked](https://github.com/aaronryank/Forked), <s>15</s> <s>13</s> 12 bytes

```
%v
>%|
^-:-&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8svyk5N@f/fULWMy061hitO10pX7f9/AA)

Forked is a very bad two-dimensional esolang I wrote a while ago. For example, the IP will wrap if you run off the bottom of the screen but the program will terminate if you run off the top.

Control flow begins traveling east at the number inputted, hits `%` to print it, then hits the `v` which redirects it south. It enters the fork (for some reason I wanted forks to be entered using three additional bytes apiece) and turns west if 1 was pushed, east if 0. To the east it hits `&` (terminate). To the west the code goes through a couple redirects that put the code in an infinite loop hitting the print command and nop `|` forever.

Due to the ridiculous fork-entering rule, I believe this is the shortest possible program in Forked to do this.

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 15 bytes

```
(-[echo@[)^:_]0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/30BDNzo1OSPfIVozzio@1uA/iKOgrqurq85liC4HAA) (includes both 0 and 1 cases.)

Abuses "fixed point" feature to choose between iterating once or infinitely.

#### How they work

```
0(-[echo@[)^:_]0  Case 0
 (-[echo@[)^:_    Try to find the fixed point of (-[echo@[), which does...
    echo@[          Print left argument once, and then
  -[                Return (left - right)
                  The input (right arg, which counts as 0th iteration) is 0
                  1st iteration is also 0, so ^:_ terminates

1(-[echo@[)^:_]0  Case 1
                  Tries to do the same, but...
                  0th iteration is 0
                  1st iteration is 1 - 0 = 1
                  2nd iteration is 1 - 1 = 0
                  3rd iteration is 1 - 0 = 1... so it oscillates between 0 and 1
                  Therefore, there's no fixed point and ^:_ runs infinitely
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Thue](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Thue), 40 bytes

```
!::=1
1+::=_+
_::=~1
+1::=~0
::=
1!+0!
```

Explanation:

Start with zero:

`0!::=1` : String becomes `1!+1`

`+1::=~0` : String becomes `1!`, and zero is printed

No more possible substitutions

Start with one:

`1!::=1` : String becomes `1+0!`

`1+::=1_+` : String becomes `1_+0!`

`_::=~1` : String becomes `1+0!` and one is printed

last two steps repeat at infimum

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##K8koTf3/30DRysrWkMtQG0TFa3PFA@k6Qy5tQxBtwAUkuQwVtQ0Uuf7/BwA)

Comment: [38 bytes](https://tio.run/##K8koTf3/38DKypZLEUQqVhlwVQHpOkMuQ0UQbcAFljM0UOT6/x8A). I still feel like it could be shorter though

Answer (score 2):

## AWK, 26 bytes

```
{while(1)print 1}{print 0}
```

[Try it online! (0)](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v/foLo8IzMnVcNQs6AoM69EwbC2GsIwqP3/XwEA)
[Try it online! (1)](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v/fsLo8IzMnVcNQs6AoM69EwbC2GsIwqP3/XwEA)

This requires some form of input; an empty string will suffice. Otherwise, I couldn't come up with a valid AWK program that begins with `0` or `1`.

Comment: As @rootbeersoup said, there is no way to implement this in Awk without having at least an empty input, EOF or line feed, for example. Nevertheless, @rootbeersoup, you may substitute the while loop for `for(;;)`, which has the same infinite effect, using one less byte.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 7 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
©@Op1}a
```

[0Test it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=MKlAT3AxfWE)

```
0          0 / 1
 ©         AND
  @   }a   return first integer that return a truthy value
           when passed through..
   Op1      return undefined and writes 1 to output
```

[1Try it online](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn/3/DQSgf/AsPaxP//AQ)

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 41 bytes

```powershell
0-ge1|iex -ov a
for(;"$a"-match"True"){1}0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/30A3PdWwJjO1QkE3v0whkSstv0jDWkklUUk3N7EkOUMppKg0VUmz2rDW4P9/AA)

I didn't think this would be possible in PowerShell, but then I remembered `-outvariable`, which is the key to making this happen. This is the first time I've *ever* used it, even in my `$DayJob`.

Checks whether the input digit is `-g`reater-than-or`e`qual to `1`. That will yield either `False` or `True` for `0` and `1`, respectively. We pipe that into `iex` (short for `Invoke-Expression` and similar to `eval`), which barfs out a spectacular error message because neither `False` nor `True` are legitimate PowerShell expressions. Thankfully, `stderr` is [ignored](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4781/42963) by default.

Then we use the handy-dandy [`-outvariable`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters?view=powershell-7) to put the output of `iex` into variable `$a`. Since the `-ov` captures *all* output into an arraylist, both stdout and stderr are captured, so we get the error message into `$a`. We then `for` loop on the condition whether `$a` (cast as a string to collapse the arraylist) regex `-match`es `"True"`. If it does, we output `1` continuously; otherwise we simply exit the `for` loop without printing anything, output `0`, and terminate.

Comment: ? [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/37DGvlolvrZGtTotv0hDs9qwttba4P9/AA "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Comment: @mazzy Haha, now I feel silly. Go ahead and post that as a separate answer, since it's significantly different than this one.

Comment: I thought I didn't understand something in the task. ok.

Comment: Thanks for `-outvariable`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Befunge-93](https://github.com/catseye/Befunge-93), 9 bytes

```
0>:#1.:_@
```

or:

```
1>:#1.:_@
```

[Try it with `0`](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT/3/38DOStlQzyre4f9/AA)

[Try it with `1`](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT/3/39DOStlQzyre4f9/AA)

Comment: Similar to the ><> answer, you don't have to create a loop when you can just use wrapping behaviour. You can do something like [this](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT/3/38BKT1HZIf7/fwA) for 7 bytes, though I think there could be a 6 byter out there

Answer (score 1):

## [Cascade](https://github.com/GuyJoKing/Cascade), 8 bytes

```
0/
?@
#|
```

[Try 0 online!](https://tio.run/##S04sTk5MSf3/30Cfy96BS7lG4f9/AA) [Try 1 online!](https://tio.run/##S04sTk5MSf3/31Cfy96BS7lG4f9/AA)

Hardcoded input makes this a lot more trivial, since we don't need to store the value of the input or anything.

Answer (score 1):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), <s>23</s> 20 bytes

```sh
=
<<<${${1+1}:-0}
$0
```

<s>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@J@UWJxqq/7flistv0hBQ8Na2cBaU9PGxsaQC0gY/FfnAitQqQZR0UY6ukaxtVxcaaV5ySWZ@XnF0VWpRfmxtgYqIGkk4fy81FhbQ4goF0gNF1DkPwA)</s>
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@J@UWJxqq6KRnFiiYGOjoO7q76b@35bLxsZGpVql2lDbsNZK16CWS8XgP1CGS5OLK600L7kkMz@vOLoqtSg/1tZABWQCknB@XmqsrSFElAukhgso8h8A)

Normally, the parameter `$0` holds the program/function name. Running `0=` sets the parameter to the empty string, which causes the recursion to break. Without any arguments, `$1` is unset, so the ${:-fallback} `0` is used instead.

Otherwise, `1=` sets `$1` to the empty string, which causes `${1+1}` to expand to `1`.

---

If the program `1` is not in the user's path or another function, then for **16 bytes**:

```sh
=1
<<<${1:-0}
$0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@J@UWJxqq6KRnFiiYGOjoO7q76b@39aQy8bGRqXa0ErXoJZLxeA/UJRLk4srrTQvuSQzP684uiq1KD/W1kAFpBtJOD8vNdbWECLKBVLDBRT5DwA)

Same principle, but with the parameter in question set to the value `1` instead of empty.

Answer (score 1):

## [Wren](https://github.com/munificent/wren), 53 bytes

That extremely long System.print ... but it doesn't matter.

```
==0?System.print(0):(0..0/0).each{|i|System.print(1)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky9Kzfv/39DW1sA@uLK4JDVXr6AoM69Ew0DTSsNAT89A30BTLzUxOaO6JrMGRYGhZu3//wA)

### Explanation

If x is the given input bit:

```
x==0  // If the input bit is 0:
?System.print(0) // Output 0 to the console
:     // Otherwise:
(0..0/0) // Generate range from 0 to 0/0 (which yields nan,
         // a negative infinity constant. No matter how
         // you increment 0, you will never get a negative.)
.each{|i|System.print(1)} // Foreach over this infinite list:
                          // Output the number 1
```

Answer (score 1):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 6 bytes

You know, the fact that input isn't taken from STDIN helps the CJam code become shorter! ([Martin Ender wrote this before](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/62734/85052))

```
{_o}h;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/37A6Pr82w/r/fwA)

### Explanation

```
1       "The input bit";
 {  }h  "A do ... while loop, taking";
        "the non-popped TOS as condition";
  _     "Duplicate the input bit";
   o    "Output to STDOUT, popping";
      ; "If the bit is 0, we discard";
        "the extra copy on the stack";
        "That is printed implicitly to the";
        "output";
```

Answer (score 1):

## Implicit, 3 bytes

```
(%)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87MLchJLS5JTM7@/99QQ1Xz/38A)

Explanation:

```
 X         Push number X (only works at start of program)
(           Create jump point 
%          Print top of stack
)            Jump to most recent jump point if top of stack is truthy
```

Answer (score 1):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 7 bytes

```
{..}do;
```

It sucks that you need to infinitely print 1, and print exactly one 0 otherwise I could take away a few characters!

If the restriction was "term on 0, hang on 1", then `{.}do` is enough. The extra point is for infinite 1s, and the semicolon is or exactly one zero (otherwise there'd be 2 with this solution).

This takes the header, then duplicates it twice. Pop the top, if it's 0, stop, pop, done. One 0 left. If it's a 1, recur the inside, duplicating 1s until your computer burns out of memory.

EDIT: Note, the Wikipedia article has `~{..p}do;` as its solution. This assumes you use the "input" area, whereas SE has slightly more flexible input rules to allow header starts.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPlv8L9aT682Jd/6/38A)

Comment: Does this actually output the 1s or just duplicate them in memory?

Comment: When programs finish, GS prints the stack.

Comment: But the program isn't going to finish, by definition

Comment: When the program crashes, it still prints the stack (explosively).

Comment: Programs are based on the assumption that they have infinite memory and time. If your program relies on halting in order to output, then it doesn't obey the run forever restriction, and vice versa

Comment: I disagree with this, since there are several languages that only actually engage in their "output" once they finish the program. Processing, for example, if you lock it in a while loop, will never output anything until the program eventually crashes, since it holds all output prints until either the draw() call is done or the program crashes.  Since this problem didn't specify we're doing a theory-question that we "don't actually have the ability to calculate" like some complexity problems do, I'd say there isn't an implicit infinite-memory quota.

Comment: I don't see any Processing answer on this question. Also, GolfScript *has* a way to explicitly output. I'm not sure if it is written down on CCCG, but submissions may assume infinite resources at any time unless explicitly restricted from doing so. Regardless, if you're assuming it only outputs on termination, then you can't say that it both outputs *and* runs forever.

Comment: [This shows my output is valid.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8507/91819)

Comment: This is not a function, this is a full program

Comment: Golfscript executes programs as insular functions. Arguably, since it needs to take input on the stack and by itself is non-functional, it's closer to the definition of "function" than "full program". Takes in a specific input and presents a specific output. Golfscript treats programs and functions pretty much identically.

Comment: Golfscript has explicit function constructs, blocks, so no, you can't count full programs as functions unless you surround them in `{}`. That doesn't really matter, since this challenge forces hard-coded input, and that rule still doesn't apply since the program still doesn't terminate. I would suggest opening up a meta question on whether non-terminating programs can output by assuming termination

Comment: Golfscript full programs use the same run-configuration as a blocked function would. Any program wrapped in {}~ would operate identically because Golfscript uses that format for compiling and running. The entire code is dumped onto the stack as a function then run as one, which runs the program. As for non-termination can output by assuming termination, I agree - I'll make a meta post on that because several solutions here only work when memory floods and the entire output is printed at once. Especially anything stuck in while() loops.

Comment: Ok, but no IO rule allows for full programs to have hard coded input. And you can apply that secons statement to any language with a function, that a series of statements works identically to a function with those statments immediately executed. I'm probably also going to end up making a meta post for this function vs program thing

Answer (score 1):

## [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), <s>11</s> 10 bytes

```
[p1=m]dsmx
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0n@/z@6wNA2NzalOLfi/38A)

[Try with 0.](https://tio.run/##S0n@/98gusDQNjc2pTi34v9/AA)

[Try with 1.](https://tio.run/##S0n@/98wusDQNjc2pTi34v9/AA)

*Thanks to user41805 for eliminating 1 byte.*

Comment: It seems the program works without `d`, while producing infinite `stack empty`s to STDERR.

Comment: @user41805 Thanks, that's interesting.  Conditionals in dc are supposed to pop two items off the stack and compare them.  But it seems that if the stack doesn't have two items on it, nothing is popped (even if there is one item), and the test is evaluated as if the two items being compared were equal (so that `=`, `!<` and `!>` are considered true, while `!=`, `<`, and `>` are considered false.  (At least that's true for one version of dc that I tested, but there are different versions floating around, and I wouldn't assume that they all behave in the same way in this regard.)

Comment: I did not understand why it worked as it did, thanks for the explanation, it is indeed interesting. Perhaps it's worth adding to the dc tips

Answer (score 1):

## [1+](http://esolangs.org/wiki/1+), <s>19</s> 15 bytes

```
11+/1<"#:[#":1#
```

A fairly trivial ungolfed solution.

[Try it 0nline!](https://tio.run/##jVVbb5tIFH7nV5zgB6DGXJys0mXjh6ZSo11FVpRtHlaUIgzjGhVm6MyQi9r@dvcMGIPt2FvLQnP5znfuZ6oXuWJ0ul6PYCVlJQLXrRKeFi8yeSaFI@tyUXAnZaVbMSHdt5fe2z8u/Ytz/083p5LwihP8TpaMT/xJTidVw6dpozO3Ftxd5NQl9BE2xyPwxzCQwzXcdVd3jV74qBSDC/8QTkq1pTZMPf8CEbd5SmhKIBfw/j1c/zf59x1cOB6CP7y7Bd85x9XN/AFu7m4fz7W8rBiXIF6EtuSshJQVBUllzqiAzV1GvtVE04QNIoNZuzUtG77/1LSMLIFRUhW1MAViZzDHrRVogL98CZQhN5ftfnNWEGqiPifhXx4tOJvBtL9Wv4qj86A/iOQLCUCHMXTo0Itwp0O4zAsCksGCAHkmaS1JFuk7JEqEPOfS9K1eN63QQFYN9Id@ZIPBjR7EkycEIdThJMnMHWknLZggmzNSCDSvhaOLzVnzWZU23NuwENKGaxvmeB9GKlx2HzsP/w0YawJSlWEk2olSCrMZGKaxG5trGM/A3zlCPU5SoVOZObcOGawDhsk@w32oOCpWmVakMrhziUTXcAXeLssgT3@Xi6RIsOIyWPAk/UqkONMPwNt8TF@xcWRAQjPUgxsvwAC@4tC897wx6Ww2tOm3bNm3ofnMbUhLVbiYkg8J5rQ5fVqpCpuj46paMTdWr4upKsKjcB4NXVGljkzBfvQUHH30jQBE59egKNtS6nHjIU60WVEt0K6Oy715Te7N/8vpO3LhxI@OY90Gy5lMJDnlw6dPQ@DkBPJzAyTPUmkPN8bandUnTLkamu2pOHc@X21XqkPhhPIRcqjuXJWd5ugo1hnqSxbCxHpTdRHjWKilaVB8AwgPsN@sE8G2hyyMZ0OGdJVgycqWBCfdCZoAadqK39h9FPmXUohlL2TGauk88RwTUtM8XfGuSE7oCVG6bY6PvCZHYftDqhmjknZdgtXrB/fYLZGDr6bM1eNiGj8M60AIKVEOZzIanYVq6UVqIqnVNDqAbx@eLfaQUuX3ftip@8ZnBmyDqfUAnO1HGjnaBqUfF4MBhcA4pklJ4ljB9Tguk5zGsd7ydTZb67Xn@2PXv/JHIz3Q/TGuxqO101SDgzH6BQ)

[Try it on1ine!](https://tio.run/##jVVbj5s4FH7nV5whD0BDIM7Mql128tCp1GpXo2g02z6sKEUEnAYt2Kxt5qK2vz09hhBIMsk2ipAv3/nO/bh6VmvOZpvNCNZKVTLw/SoRafGskidaeKoul4XwUl76FZfKf/N6@ua31@Tqkvzu50xRUQmK38mKiwmZ5GxSNXyGMbrwayn8Zc58yh5gezwCMoaBHK7hrru6a/TCR60YfPiLClrqLXNhNiVXiLjNU8pSCrmEd@/g5p/J32/hypsi@P3bWyDeJa4@LD7Bh7vbh0sjLysuFMhnaawELyHlRUFTlXMmYXuX0f9qahjSBZnBvN3ajgvffhhGRlfAGa2KWtoSsXNY4NYJDMBfvgLGkVuodr89KyizUZ@XiK8PDlzMYdZf618l0HkwP8nkKw3AhDF06HAa4c6EcJUXFBSHJQX6RNNa0Swy90i0CH3KlU2cXjer0EBeDfSHJHLBElYPEskjghDqCZpk9p60lxZc0u0ZLSSa18LRxeas@axLF@5dWErlwo0LC7wPIx0ut4/dFP8NGGsCUp1hJNqLUgrzOVi2tR@bGxjPgewdoR4vqdCpzF44xwzOEcPkkOE@1BwVr2wn0hncu0SiG7iG6T7LIE9/lsukSLDiMliKJP2XKnlhHoF3@Zi9YOPIgoRlqAc30wAD@IJDi97zxqSL@dCmX7Ll0Ibms3AhLXXhYkreJ5jT5vRxrStsgY7rasXcOL0urqsIj8JFNHRFlzoyBYfR03D0kVgByM6vQVG2pdTjxkOcbLOiW6BdnZZ79ZLcq/@XM/fkwgmJTmP9Biu4ShQ958Pnz0Pg5AzySwOkT0prD7fGup3VZ0y5Hpo91XHufL7erXSHwhnlI@TQ3bkuO83RSaw31JcspY31pusixrFQK9ti@AZQEWC/OWeC7Q5ZuMiGDOk6wZJVLQlOujM0AdK0Fb@1@yTyD60Qy16qjNfKexQ5JqRmeboWXZGc0ROidNscH0VNT8IOh1QzRhXrugSrlwT32C2Rh6@myvXjYlvfLedICClRDmcyGp2FejmN9ETSq1l0BN89PDvsMaXO7/2wUw@NzyzYBdPoATjbTzRytAtKPy4GAwqBccySksaxhptxXCY5i2Oz5etsdjYbQsjYJ9dkNDIDk4xxNR5tvKYaPIzRTw)

**Explanation:**

Firstly, in this language, `1` pushes 1 and `0` is a NOP.

The program consists of two parts: `11+/1<` which converts the internal input into the corresponding number and `1##":"1+1<1+#` which is basically the Truth Machine.

Another nice feature of 1+ is the "rotate" operation `/` which leave the stack unmodified if there's only one number in the stack and swaps the two numbers if there's two.

```
11+                  [Pushes 2]
   /                 [Rotate the stack]
    1<               [Converts 2 to 0 and leave 1 as-is]
      "#:[#":1#      [See https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/208961/87986]
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pxem](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Pxem), filename only: 11 bytes.

```
0.z1.o.a0.o
```

[0Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVh7V9rKFv@/n2JII5khCckgKBKjUvBazlGK1rqsgK5AgoIhcEhQNHC@eu@eSRAIvV3XtTQzv/2c/ZiHz/7Tr8@fi86B1d3vOp1cL7dbtPf1vb1uwdb3Cr2O1dNtPZcv6IUCLXzynQCpztSYDi3/Gel6Lmc4s/FoEqDzykP5/NysGDh4Gzvo0Qm6I6@XTvNZdzQcWp5NjjTbedG8qeui3FGaptOxcKN8/dUURBzzIXW8VMBJRAzZRy4tooG6EJZmf9Rrtw/fr6tmTtd3l2Dj2/fa7fnPh8q3q6vTyrVJjSYSxPBL@fvXh5vTq@@1b/WS/LYQkIneUDud5qsaofHI78@imfwlErn7HxLOcOpagYP8J84/GgcwfB1NbH/s9oN02nL7lo/URySJIZUF8URYSKbEvlI6Xf9xfl65qJolbgMze7bhP/V7gcHHiPHFgNN9GiHxM2GWKbOcAkO5kWsfpSH0L5aLhBTqWa7vCPP5Oo2r5tKzue/YSPK1mfamGT78edckrvAdtZkQ5wKepWgXEzyCJJQ9pL4EUzoPJkit@KjV1NWDNpKaLS/TluaPE2eMspFy7T6/J2phqWyIHaNuaC2Pzxtg7j6bbXmaZnTKxiKaNu@ZHkpzojbWjGAdLOrbGKVU1EYJcP9gG6MUpL0kY3Ebo3pB1PpJxt1t7AD4HpIYWO4msL39bYxSEPaT69vdxigFF1@SjHvbGNUhYr2k2/o2RnWImJP08WAbozQvapOk6dw2RilIvyYZ97cxmgN/ZknG4jZGc@DjW5LxYBujOfDnPZkE/TcYuGMlF13YxiiF2AZJy/ltjOrgzjAZ7/1tjOrgjp00XdzG8pB@OYmBi2oC2wW@VBIDr8UkBs7sMGwhzXHXircLm8RNyftVC89YU84MG/rvjEm3cLZFWrjlsb/ZTIuIWmu3lWtRDbh8LZuBbp1t9nfJNcRUqDVfZ2/vlt3WUmHd6LigcGG8QbNrSDO05n1MZSUuasjWNnSoHpJi8837E6UNdsED3IyG4ELuBDEXnmKeCEfZDJC4Z5F1WM@YuylqCkM74AKkOIRZKvRhVNbGRucS0IhNOQEFH4z2B6OtVZeMG2xLShyH0sQQw8jcCWKqYYvj3Ki8RIIyD62YqgOl5TWR@t7O2ExbMFlDYEk8Pu1osRonWcA25jmNFmdFUgvwtnT5oTLLfQsuE3tuHI@vEJlqGeIyi5PLI7uKWxSfs1gT/41ciTyJs/47QQktj461hGj9HnatjuOaptCiAgn5SnBzPPL6D13/pedMgqGcEnfUNuNuUUwM7THiYfXYCqnSWjBSA7doTLPWXfKnHSywhAgKkz6GsVASTgSFmyWL2OAm/5@Yq6LWmTjWM59A3spYcEejMfJGARpaQfep7z0KwCotlytjonUwJdw3lU/UeJbiMz2aiDD5ZznZ4RPGBs3IG1HqjSZxrMAjwyChZHx0qbSQCPn1n3r54tSUdD37TrOjrKVnR9Knyrf69Wn92pSkT3g86XtBDw5zzinGJGH@2kVql8Bx/cufdE3py@lZrR5CamTfcWziT@Aahflw0Zt63aA/8lADV0n4vfms/I1J26waMGzL8op@ikk4cYLpxEMpGXhWlL9WFMCP6Iry94rC1K0I1xsEZlKla@RbfEXCKxO4uBuqasTMVyueKa6QkK8fVVboGb5S7j50wzXR7XvOkX4s6iV1zbGvkQGRGrw87nntyVAlgkA2IBRB2@Z/MPNTz1yzXcYXS48u5gKkEuLPrqL9AK2ZHsPSX5/6roNTEFIyWo8kTEIA5/MpvgXaiuDhmnKjVBWXsCxywfDGBB7DNV3Hewye8A0xWEHV4D5bOzRdg0wxrpqwFj@Y4BulJssKJeRfga9LOK7K@WIpXyCLlZE@WG/gsw3DD/hCqSh3yk8SXphC9qGE6tAWFrKdbn8I90tYrPPoTOA7ngaCUTFB3LgDH5gvrKbB3fz@YSWdrhwWioQ3mgFY5V/hPt/cLbRF2CPuzHxercTCUS8CCy5GYjQPAamY5m6OhBELXP2Dvjd1FizijLVymC8Cz1FhnzAoMr4yG2kmP038k6CKmi8aLHtGA99lfq6ttbuMfgNfbwTBXxJu15P1AjkZKDckrJk6tzgweR1D@AesbJWBqrbNG5YoNqu1OQh5aPP5oL0W@snKNEQU8/4kGVYDawZfV02z7c0MXyrcVgrakUU4BbNLXiI35uUh441lb1ZCb38UOvq90PuHG0yKu6FuuBIsF/MEvWtukIZAeoZiQfAyamBGXyN2sAUBjUr8L1bhDWwdg7hssUiUbuOIGKsdI2NSNZfB1qFOMixn8F0L6j9JfYO4Y27jxeJBxiVQMWBGyO7AwZCFahRK6M6ZwD2p/9L3QY3ACoUlxToeHLnHgx235O4MSnys8THkaBHtsOCZqbehHOAxl9ibhXmXCNLKuR5EYoPrY@/eflz94W1lRodSdBOAixYcUuyNq068ZzrvTmFkS0hCai@3PL3g4tLAacIeeWvuOLyYo1MxhMLlBf0sy4YsDw4x24RZ0ULIo/AP4ikMiPH7ZbDl2o7rwDsY8gytEG9P0CCyXDsEcZlGLcFPmhrXKFPok2jTl6N5eyEZ7KRi/wCAq1IX8X8STFmHjIbsyQvgZAtcxdDOI7We32CYz/EYnt9leNP3bcUJ@kNHGXfHU@XFfzdseLiT9Rzk//zARYHVd@H6ml8LMLtCh0V2jeGXJWluvT6DLmSZao7m9/PF3b18EUmhJZuivjitV@NTw4JDX/j0f@c/1hpHh30ESAAc@AInSaIOdzD4EZAfpQcLOyNBEXUizWfW5BFiUJuhOHOzT@jXfwE)

[1Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVh7V9rKFv@/n2JII5khCckgKBKjUvBazlGK1rqsgK5AgoIhcEhQNHC@eu@eSRAIvV3XtTQzv/2c/ZiHz/7Tr8@fi86B1d3vOp1cL7dbtPf1vb1uwdb3Cr2O1dNtPZcv6IUCLXzynQCpztSYDi3/Gel6Lmc4s/FoEqDzykP5/NysGDh4Gzvo0Qm6I6@XTvNZdzQcWp5NjjTbedG8qeui3FGaptOxcKN8/dUURBzzIXW8VMBJRAzZRy4tooG6EJZmf9Rrtw/fr6tmTtd3l2Dj2/fa7fnPh8q3q6vTyrVJjSYSxPBL@fvXh5vTq@@1b/WS/LYQkIneUDud5qsaofHI78@imfwlErn7HxLOcOpagYP8J84/GgcwfB1NbH/s9oN02nL7lo/URySJIZUF8URYSKbEvlI6Xf9xfl65qJolbgMze7bhP/V7gcHHiPHFgNN9GiHxM2GWKbOcAkO5kWsfpSH0L5aLhBTqWa7vCPP5Oo2r5tKzue/YSPK1mfamGT78edckrvAdtZkQ5wKepWgXEzyCJJQ9pL4EUzoPJkit@KjV1NWDNpKaLS/TluaPE2eMspFy7T6/J2phqWyIHaNuaC2Pzxtg7j6bbXmaZnTKxiKaNu@ZHkpzojbWjGAdLOrbGKVU1EYJcP9gG6MUpL0kY3Ebo3pB1PpJxt1t7AD4HpIYWO4msL39bYxSEPaT69vdxigFF1@SjHvbGNUhYr2k2/o2RnWImJP08WAbozQvapOk6dw2RilIvyYZ97cxmgN/ZknG4jZGc@DjW5LxYBujOfDnPZkE/TcYuGMlF13YxiiF2AZJy/ltjOrgzjAZ7/1tjOrgjp00XdzG8pB@OYmBi2oC2wW@VBIDr8UkBs7sMGwhzXHXircLm8RNyftVC89YU84MG/rvjEm3cLZFWrjlsb/ZTIuIWmu3lWtRDbh8LZuBbp1t9nfJNcRUqDVfZ2/vlt3WUmHd6LigcGG8QbNrSDO05n1MZSUuasjWNnSoHpJi8837E6UNdsED3IyG4ELuBDEXnmKeCEfZDJC4Z5F1WM@YuylqCkM74AKkOIRZKvRhVNbGRucS0IhNOQEFH4z2B6OtVZeMG2xLShyH0sQQw8jcCWKqYYvj3Ki8RIIyD62YqgOl5TWR@t7O2ExbMFlDYEk8Pu1osRonWcA25jmNFmdFUgvwtnT5oTLLfQsuE3tuHI@vEJlqGeIyi5PLI7uKWxSfs1gT/41ciTyJs/47QQktj461hGj9HnatjuOaptCiAgn5SnBzPPL6D13/pedMgqGcEnfUNuNuUUwM7THiYfXYCqnSWjBSA7doTLPWXfKnHSywhAgKkz6GsVASTgSFmyWL2OAm/5@Yq6LWmTjWM59A3spYcEejMfJGARpaQfep7z0KwCotlytjonUwJdw3lU/UeJbiMz2aiDD5ZznZ4RPGBs3IG1HqjSZxrMAjwyChZHx0qbSQCPn1n3r54tSUqJ59p9lR1tKzI@lT5Vv9@rR@bUrSJzye9L2gB4c55xRjkjB/7SK1S@C4/uVPuqb05fSsVg8hNbLvODbxJ3CNwny46E29btAfeaiBqyT83nxW/sakbVYNGLZleUU/xSScOMF04qGUDDwryl8rCuBHdEX5e0Vh6laE6w0CM6nSNfItviLhlQlc3A1VNWLmqxXPFFdIyNePKiv0DF8pdx@64Zro9j3nSD8W9ZK65tjXyIBIDV4e97z2ZKgSQSAbEIqgbfM/mPmpZ67ZLuOLpUcXcwFSCfFnV9F@gNZMj2Hpr09918EpCCkZrUcSJiGA8/kU3wJtRfBwTblRqopLWBa5YHhjAo/hmq7jPQZP@IYYrKBqcJ@tHZquQaYYV01Yix9M8I1Sk2WFEvKvwNclHFflfLGUL5DFykgfrDfw2YbhB3yhVJQ75ScJL0wh@1BCdWgLC9lOtz@E@yUs1nl0JvAdTwPBqJggbtyBD8wXVtPgbn7/sJJOVw4LRcIbzQCs8q9wn2/uFtoi7BF3Zj6vVmLhqBeBBRcjMZqHgFRMczdHwogFrv5B35s6CxZxxlo5zBeB56iwTxgUGV@ZjTSTnyb@SVBFzRcNlj2jge8yP9fW2l1Gv4GvN4LgLwm368l6gZwMlBsS1kydWxyYvI4h/ANWtspAVdvmDUsUm9XaHIQ8tPl80F4L/WRlGiKKeX@SDKuBNYOvq6bZ9maGLxVuKwXtyCKcgtklL5Eb8/KQ8cayNyuhtz8KHf1e6P3DDSbF3VA3XAmWi3mC3jU3SEMgPUOxIHgZNTCjrxE72IKARiX@F6vwBraOQVy2WCRKt3FEjNWOkTGpmstg61AnGZYz@K4F9Z@kvkHcMbfxYvEg4xKoGDAjZHfgYMhCNQoldOdM4J7Uf@n7oEZghcKSYh0PjtzjwY5bcncGJT7W@BhytIh2WPDM1NtQDvCYS@zNwrxLBGnlXA8iscH1sXdvP67@8LYyo0MpugnARQsOKfbGVSfeM513pzCyJSQhtZdbnl5wcWngNGGPvDV3HF7M0akYQuHygn6WZUOWB4eYbcKsaCHkUfgH8RQGxPj9Mthybcd14B0MeYZWiLcnaBBZrh2CuEyjluAnTY1rlCn0SbTpy9G8vZAMdlKxfwDAVamL@D8JpqxDRkP25AVwsgWuYmjnkVrPbzDM53gMz@8yvOn7tuIE/aGjjLvjqfLivxs2PNzJeg7yf37gosDqu3B9za8FmF2hwyK7xvDLkjS3Xp9BF7JMNUfz@/ni7l6@iKTQkk1RX5zWq/GpYcGhL3z6v/Mfa42jwz4CJAAOfIGTJFGHOxj8CMiP0oOFnZGgiDqR5jNr8ggxqM1QnLnZJ/Trvw)

If you are not familiar with Pxem: `.z ... .a` is "while stack size<2 or pop!=pop; do something; done" (sorry I misdescript the function).

Also, pushing literates are done backwards; if program begins with `10.z`, then 48 is pushed first, then 49 next. Then the branching is done.

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 4 bytes

```
[{1₴
```

[0Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=0%5B%7B1%E2%82%B4&inputs=&header=&footer=)
[1Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=1%5B%7B1%E2%82%B4&inputs=&header=&footer=)

```
[       If the top of the stack is truthy (i.e. 1):
 {      Repeat forever:
  1₴    Print 1
```

Answer (score 0):

## [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/), 9 bytes

```
1c0
=;G;D
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K05N0U3PK/3/3zDZgMvW2t3a5f9/AA)

(sed requires at the minimum an empty line as input to run.)

sed cycles the input line-by-line. The first line is read into the pattern space first, on which the program is run, at the end of which the resulting pattern space will be implicitly output allowing the next cycle to commence with the next line. Commands can be line-addressed, meaning that they will run only on the specified lines. For example, `11c0` will change the 11th line of input to 0, whilst `1c0` changes the 1st line of input to 0.

If `0` is inserted as the first character, the first line becomes `01c0`, i.e. the first line is changed to 0, which ends up printed. A new cycle is started immediately afterwards, and since there are no more lines, the program exits.

If `1` is inserted as the first character, the first line becomes `11c0`, i.e. change the 11th line to 0. This does not happen, because there is only 1 line of input, the empty line. The program proceeds to `=` which prints the line number, i.e. 1. `G` appends a newline followed by the hold space (starts with being the empty line) to the pattern space, which now contains just a newline. `D` deletes the first line of the pattern space until and including the newline, and restarts the cycle with the resulting pattern space without consuming the next line of input. This creates the infinite loop, and since the line number stays at 1, `1` + newline is printed out forever. [source](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Other-Commands.html)

Answer (score 0):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 4 bytes

```
WQ|c
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=WQ%7Cc&i=)

prepend with `0` or `1`.  Bonus: also works as a regular truth machine with input

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 23 bytes

```perl
?$_=1:say 0;say while$_
```

[True](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/9/QXiXe1tCqOLFSwcAaRJZnZOakqsT///8vv6AkMz@v@L@ur6megaEBAA)

[False](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/9/AXiXe1tCqOLFSwcAaRJZnZOakqsT///8vv6AkMz@v@L@ur6megaEBAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [MAWP](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MAWP), 13 bytes

```
!~M1A?:?.[!:]
```

**Explanation:**

```
               Stack starts with 1.
!              Duplicates 0 or 1  [1,0,0] or [1,1,1]
 ~             Reverses the stack [0,0,1] or [1,1,1]
  M            Adds top 2 elements[0,1]   or [1,2]
   1A          Subtract 1 from top[0,0]   or [1,1]
     ?:        If top of stack is 0, print it, otherwise do nothing
       ?.      If top of stack is 0, end program
         [!:]  Infinite loop which duplicates top of stack and prints it
```

[Try it!](https://8dion8.github.io/?code=0!%7EM1A%3F%3A%3F.%5B!%3A%5D%0A&input=1)

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 3 bytes

```
i[?
```

[0Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fIDPa/v9/AA)

[1Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fMDPa/v9/AA)

```
i[?  # full program
i    # if...
     # (implicit) hardcoded input...
i    # is 1...
 [   # forever...
  ?  # output...
     # (implicit) hardcoded input
     # implicit output
```